# Python Problems with the bindings module when nuitka compile a program that includes tkinterweb

Tags: python, binding, nuitka

I am using nuitka to compile a program that imports the tkinterweb module and works fine, but when I package it with nuitka it doesn't work

I try to use the `--include-module=tkinterweb` parameter but it comes up as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bindings'`, so I used the `--include-module=bindings` parameter again, this time in the compile process on the `FATAL: Error, failed to locate module ' bindings' you asked to include.`

ps I've tried pyinstaller and made sure the program runs successfully with the --collect-all parameter, but I don't want to use any other tools, especially pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in similar situation (and using pyinstaller) i managed to make it work by adding collect all for pygubu and tkinterweb
Documented it here.
https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu-designer/wiki/Pyinstaller-troubleshooting

Comes down to this:

## Collections of issues found when building with pyinstaller.

### ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageFont' from 'PIL'

```py
hiddenimports = ["FMD3","PIL.ImageFont","PIL.ImageDraw"]
```

### Exception: Class "tkinterweb.HtmlFrame" not mapped

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all
datas = []
binaries=[]
collects = [collect_all('tkinterweb'), collect_all('pygubu')]
for ret in collects:
    datas += ret[0]
    binaries += ret[1]
    hiddenimports += ret[2]
```